# How to import javax.smartcard library in android studio?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, android-studio

I am currently using `javax.smartcardio` in a spring project using eclipse. I added the library in eclipse by going to `Build Path` > `Configure Build Path` > `Module Dependencies` and then selecting the `javax.smartcardio` from the list then `Apply and Close`.

Now I am working on an android project which is using the same hardware that I used in spring project. As of my current knowledge, I know that `javax.smartcardio` is present already in Java SDK. Now I need to import the same module in Android Studio to use in my android project but don't know from where to add the `javax.smartcardio` library into my android studio project.

Looking forward to hearing soon. Thanks

Comment: "I know that javax.smartcardio is present already in Java SDK" -- it is not part of the Android SDK, and last I checked you cannot add `java.*` or `javax.*` libraries to an Android SDK project. I recommend that you talk to the manufacturer of the hardware and ask how they recommend that you use Android in conjunction with that hardare.